# Pagination custom category page template

Tags: categories, pagination, page-template

I want to display product categories on separated pages. Should be 6 posts of 1 category on a page, and if we have more than 6 postings in this category, - so I want to display a pagination. I googled hours, tried a lot, but nothing was working. I used the blank theme "base" from themify.

The only thing I got to work is this:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$result = new WP_Query('cat=5');
$args_pagi = array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
'total' => $result->max_num_pages,
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') )
);

$args = array(
        'orderby'        => 'post_date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'category'        => '5',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'post_status'        => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'            => $paged,
    );

$myposts = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach( $myposts->posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?> 
    <ul class="recent-posts-2">
        <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array( 120,120 ), array( 'class' => 'recent-thumbs' )); ?></a> 
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="lol">
<?php echo paginate_links( $args_pagi);?> 
</div>
```

The problem is, the output was mixed by categories, - shows 5 posts of cat.`5` and 1 of cat.`7`, shows four products of cat.`7` on page 2 and two of cat.`5`. (there are 8 postings of cat.`5` in db)

Under  `/wp-admin` "Reading", the setting is 6 posts per page.

What is wrong?

Comment: there is no `category` argument for `WP_Query`, use `cat` to pass a category ID

Comment: Hello Chip and Milo, - Milos tip was right, it seems it works now. ;-)))  Great, thanks a lot.